# DIVs in SVG code

Tags: html, css, svg

StackOverflow
I used to work with HTML, but now I am working with full-SVG project. I need to create a simple layout: 2 rectangles, placed in a column with a gap, and a text in each of them. The only way I can do that is to manually position rectangles and texts with `x` and `y`.

Question: how can I do it like in HTML (using `div` and relative positioning), in which a text is a child of a rectangle and aligned in its center?

That is how I made it:

```
<g>
    <rect height="40" width="100"/>
    <text alignment-baseline="baseline" x="30" y="33" font-family="Verdana" style="fill: #fff;" font-size="35">50</text>
</g>
```

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @benM I've added my version to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVG isn't about flow layout like HTML is. If you want typographic layout capabilities within SVG, you can use the SVG `foreignElement` to embed HTML into SVG eg.

```
<svg viewBox="...">
  <g>
    <foreignObject x="10" y="20" height="20" width="80">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><p>this</p></div>
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><p>that</p></div>
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
</svg>
```

and then use CSS floats, flexbox, width-percentages or whatever style on the `div`s to achieve the desired effect.

Edit: foreignObject doesn't work on IE11, though

Comment: Thank you!
But how can it be so flexible if the only way to create a layout is to manually position all the elements?

Comment: SVG is for maps, diagrams, vector backgrounds, icons/avators, games content etc. rather than for layout or designed to replace HTML (and why would it when you have CSS and HTML already)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use filter, you can draw "div-like" text box at SVG.

But this is a bit technical and not useful compared to original html's `div` element, because this "div-like" does not have any useful feature as text wrapping, flexible border style, box shadows and so on. Thus you should use original `div` element with `foreignObject` element.

Sample code:

```css
/*color setting*/
.bgcolor{flood-color:yellow;}
.bordercolor{flood-color:orange;}

/*filter setting*/
.divLike{filter:url(#divLike);}
.divLike>text{filter:url(#text);}
```

```html
<!--define filters-->
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <!--create bounding box of text-->
        <filter id="text" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feFlood x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1" class="bgcolor"/>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
        <!--wrap bounding box by feMorphology-->
        <filter id="divLike" x="-1" y="-1" width="3" height="3">
            <!--create padding-->
            <feFlood class="bgcolor"/>
            <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in"/>
            <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="10" result="padding"/>
            <!--create border-->
            <feFlood class="bordercolor"/>
            <feComposite in2="padding" operator="in"/>
            <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="5" result="border"/>
            <!--marge these graphics-->
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="border"/>
                <feMergeNode in="padding"/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>

<!--text layout-->
<svg width="500px" height="200px">    
    <g class="divLike">
        <text x="50" y="50" font-size="30">This is <tspan font-weight="bold">div-like</tspan> effect.</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```